# Can we use gradient or clipping mask if we make SVG file for cricut and used for printing?

Tags: print-design

I am very confused as I make a large file of design as my niche is shirt print and I am giving SVG files for cricut and someone told me the use of clipping mask is wrong and you have to cahnge

Answer (score 1):

These devices are cutting machines, and they rely on paths to guide the cutting head. So, if you have anything that is not a path, such as effects, gradients, strokes or masks, then these won't work. It will just ignore them. These machines do not print anything, although some models can fit a pen to the device, which works like a plotter.

There is a [youtube video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s1iRQh3FhzM) which gives a run down of the basic capabilities of these machines.

The usual way to get around the clipping mask problem is not to use clipping masks at all, but to physically cut the artwork up using boolean operations, and then delete the pieces that aren't part of the design. This will work in all vector software.

If you already have a clipping mask, you will have to release it and use that to cut up your design.

If you have access to Adobe Illustrator, you could also use the Shape Builder tool to delete pieces that aren't needed. It can make the process easier.